# Looping F-Curve Modifier?

Tags: animation, modifiers, fcurves

I was wondering if there is a way to exploit the F-Curve Modifiers to create a seamless loop from a Noise modifier further up the stack.

What I would imagine it would do is behave kind of like the Restrict Frame Range Influence In/Out parameters, except that it would oversample the region and crossfade the extra parameter samples (similar to a crossfade loop in video).

I can sort of get this behavior just by using the restrict range feature, but I have to go back to the parameter's default value at the loop point.

Thanks!